# How to deal with the ios Launch files

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

It has been a while since I created my last app and I missed the change with the launch file (since titanium 5.2.0).
I want my app to have a custom splashscreen (full screen image). In the past I used the various png files for the splashscreens Default.png, Default@2x.png etc.

I'm testing with the launch file and the custom Storyboard. At the moment it's not clear to me how I can achieve the behavior i want: A full screen image in the splash screen. 
What is the best approach?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-iOSgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions and take a look at the `Purpose` column. You'll see 9 splash screen sizes. You have to make each of them and put them in `app/assets/iphone`. Note that you have to name them exactly as told in the table.

This worked for me, Ti-5.4.0 tested on iPhone 7, iPad Air, iPhone 4S and iPhone 6S Plus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gerben. The way you described is exactly how i did it in my previous apps. Now I noticed that the images didn't appear (i started a default Alloy project). I can try to do it like you described but I wonder if that is the best approach for future apps.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and fully re-install(remove the app first) the app on your device?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5.2 storyboards were introduced. You can use them or you can disable it and use the "old" method to implement splashscreens.

To disable it, add this to tiapp: (of course, within the existing `ios` section in tiapp

```
<ios>
    <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
</ios>
```

To use it, look at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Launch_Files) how to implement it correctly.